# Comparing statistics of networks of different sizes

Tags: graph-theory

Hi This maybe a basic Stats question.

Let say I have 3 networks of different sizes. Size in terms of number of nodes and links. 
Network n1, n2 and n3 have v1, v2 and v3 nodes and l1, l2 and l3 links. That is all we know about the networks.

For each of these networks we compute some parameters based on some criteria. For example,

param1 = no. of nodes with criteria 1

param2 = no. of nodes with criteria 2

param3 = no. of nodes with criteria 3

Result

```
   nodes links param1 param2 param3 
n1   v1    l1     a      b      c   
n2   v2    l2     d      e      f   
n3   v3    l3     g      h      i
```

Question

If I average (a+d+g/3) to get the expected param1 across networks, would that make sense knowing that the size of the networks is different and the parameters are a function of the size of the network? How to reconcile with the fact that different networks have different sizes and therefore cannot be compared directly.

Answer (score 2):

A typical strategy would be to compare the *proportion* of the nodes in each network satisfying each of the criteria instead of the *number* of nodes. So for example, if your networks had $100, 200, 400$ nodes respectively and the `param1` for each of these networks was $50, 60, 80$, then the corresponding proportions of nodes of this particular type would be $50/100, 60/200$ and $80/300$, or $0.5, 0.3, 0.2$. Then it would make sense to average these numbers; the average proportion of nodes of this type is $(0.5+0.3+0.2)/3 = 0.333$. So if, say, you had a new network with $1000$ nodes, you might guess that it would have about $0.333 \times 1000 = 333$ nodes of the desired type, all other things being equal.

Comment: I second this. I can't prove it, but I suspect that using absolute levels instead of proportions would produce a test statistic that depends on the size of the network. For what it's worth Matt Jackson & his ilk usually seem to speak in terms of edge "density" rather than total number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the fact that these are networks or graphs have no bearing on the problem you had in mind. Instead, it sounds like you have three binomial trials, with $n$ values $n_1, n_2, n_3$, respectively, and estimated proportions $\hat p_1 = \frac{a}{n_1}$, $\hat p_2 = \frac{d}{n_1}$, $\hat p_1 = \frac{g}{n_1}$, respectively, for this first criteria you're interested in. These you should be able to analyze with the usual $t$-test.

Beyond this, if you want to test all three graphs at once, recognize that you basically have a two-way anova. The blocks are which graph you're in, and the parameters are the treatment. The responses are of course 0 and 1, which you might consider remapping to -1 and 1. I recommend researching two-level factorial designs, as in Chapter 29 of [Applied Linear Statistical Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007310874X)

Comment: I thought as much. It is not exactly a graph question but a question about sampling from different populations. Considering that a t-test should probably be enough, however I wanted to get an other opinion. Thanks.